# How do I put the mean into an arrayList, and how do I put the scores in the input file into their own arrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, mean

My assignment is:

> Suppose there is a file called Numbers.txt that contains a number of
>   lines of data.  Each line contains three integers.  Write a program
>   that reads each line of data from the file and places the average of
>   the three integers into an ArrayList of integers. After all the data
>   has been read and the averages calculated your program should write
>   the averages to a file called Output.out

The test data that is in the input file includes the following:

```
79 84 90
92 78 85
90 88 92
98 94 92
88 78 84
```

Here's the code that I wrote as an attempt to complete the assignment:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class MeanCalc 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        (FileReader reader = new FileReader("Numbers.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);        
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Output.txt");        
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer))
        {

        ArrayList<String> scores = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> avgs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while(in.hasNextLine())
        {
          String nextLine = in.nextLine();
          StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(nextLine);
          if(st.countTokens() == 3)
          {
             String score1 = st.nextToken();
             String score2 = st.nextToken();
             String score3 = st.nextToken();

             try
             {
                int s1 = Integer.parseInt(score1);
                int s2 = Integer.parseInt(score2);
                int s3 = Integer.parseInt(score3);
                scores.add(score1);
                scores.add(score2);
                scores.add(score3);
                avgs.add((s1 + s2 + s3)/3);
             }
             catch(NumberFormatException e)
             {System.out.println("Invalid data: " + nextLine);}
          }
        }
        if(scores.size() > 0)
           {
            calcMean(avgs); 
            for(int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++)
               out.printf("%-20s  %5.2d\n", scores.get(i), avgs.get(i));
           }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error processing file: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
public static double calcMean(ArrayList<Integer> table)
{
      double total = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < table.size(); ++i)
         total += table.get(i);
      return total/table.size();
}
}
```

The code that I wrote is not working properly, as it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 2
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkInteger(Formatter.java:2984)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2729)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2560)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.format(PrintWriter.java:905)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.printf(PrintWriter.java:804)
    at MeanCalc.main(MeanCalc.java:51)
```

I'm not sure what mistakes I'm making with line 51, and I was hoping somebody could help me improve on my program

Comment: shouldn't average be an ArrayList of double, otherwise, you might lose precision on some computations?

Comment: The assignment specifically asks to place the average of the 3 integers in each line into an arrayList of integers.

Comment: if that's the requirement then I am on your side ;).

Comment: @Michael yes as I had assumed previously, However considering OP has been told to do it that way, I guess there is no other option, even though I still believe it's incorrect to use integral values for average as most people would ;).

Comment: @Aominè That's just made me realise that the question's not even explicit about which average to use. Back in the day, I would've probably used the geometric mean or median just to annoy them. (and probably also got a zero)

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` specifier requires an integer argument. In line `out.printf("%-20s  %5.2d\n", scores.get(i), avgs.get(i))` you are using the `%d` specifier with a decimal point (`.2`).

Comment: When I got rid of the decimal point for the %d specifier, but I still got several errors: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
 at MeanCalc.main(MeanCalc.java:51)

Comment: scores and averages are not of the same size, just output the averages to the output file `out.printf("%5d\n", avgs.get(i));`. Or concat the scores rather than adding them to `scores`, i.e. `scores.add(score1 + " " + score2 + " " + score3);`

Comment: Change scores.size() to avgs.size()